# How can peripheral manager understands which is the CBCentral(device) trying to access the service/characterstics

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an app which has peripheral service running but it needs to validate the central before giving the response. I was looking at CBCentral api doc it has identifier. but i couldn't find a way to send my identifier in my CBCentral manager. My central manager will be an app which has random identifier. How can i validate in peripheral service who is trying to access my data..

To give more details of my app i have an app which works as receive mode(CBCentral Manager) and send mode (Peripheral Manager). Only selected CBCentral manager can access my peripheral manager service. How to restrict this.

Regards

Hashique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can take.

One approach is to implement a challenge/response mechanism between your central and your peripheral.  Your peripheral exposes a value via an attribute, your central takes this value, manipulates it in some what known only to your code and then writes it back to the peripheral.  The peripheral can then perform the same manipulation and validate the response before making any other values available.

The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require any user interaction, but in theory your code can be reverse engineered and the hashing algorithm replicated - how much of a risk this is depends on the value of the communication and the impact of unauthorised access

A second approach is to use the encryption and security built-in to BLE.  If your peripheral marks an attribute as encryption required then the user will be taken through a pairing process using a passcode as with traditional Bluetooth.

The advantage of this approach is that it uses Bluetooth standard capabilities, so you don't need to write any special code.  The disadvantage is that you need some user interface on your peripheral so you can provide the passcode and it doesn't prevent the user from pairing your peripheral from any central as long as they have control over both devices.

Comment: Thanks .. I did the first approach. Asking user to pair will be overkill for our app.. Thanks again